# Python script can't connect to firebase when used as service with systemd on Raspberry PI 3B

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, raspberry-pi, systemd

**Quick summary to what I want to achieve:**

- I’m making a python script that communicates with firebase-Realtime
  database running on Raspberry Pi 3 B and depending on the values
  stored in the database, the script will light up a LED or shut it
  down. The script will also always start on bootup.

**Background to what I’m using (software/hardware/configuration):**

- Raspberry Pi 3 B - Raspbian installed with NOOBS version 3.0.0
- Using Python 3.5.3 with [Pyrebase libraries](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase)
- I've enabled SSH and remote
  desktop on Raspberry PI 3 B, so I only work with Raspberry PI using
  remote desktop.

**What I have achieved so far and what works:**

- Python script does everything that I want it to do when started from
  terminal or Python IDLE (it connects to firebase, then reads the data
  via stream and updates LED status whenever the data changes in the
  database).
- I managed also to launch the script as service using
  systemd.

**What is wrong:**

This part of the code is supposed to react in two ways depending on if there is
or isn’t internet  connection (NOTE that this works as intended when
running script from terminal/idle):
..

```
#Test of connection ...
GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.HIGH)
while have_internet() == False:
    GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.LOW)
    print("No connection ...")
    sleep(1)

GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.HIGH)
```

1. If there ISN’T an internet connection, the LED stays on for
   approx. 5 seconds, and then the while loop gets stuck and turns off
   the LED. Then it waits until there is internet connection - turns on
   the LED back and continues. This works - and I’ve checked it by
   rebooting the PI and unplugging WLAN from my home router, the LED
   turns off and waits … then when I plug the WLAN back into my router,
   LED turns on again.
2. If there IS an internet connection the code continues with
   LED TURNED ON.

**But when I run the script from reboot as service using systemd this happens:**

1. The LED turns on as it should in the start.
2. The while loop does what
   it is supposed to do: waits until there is an internet connection and
   then turns on the LED.
3. And then the LED stays ON the whole time. I
   change the data in the firebase-Realtime database, and it doesn’t
   respond to it! The LED stays on no matter how I change the data in
   the database.

I’m so confused here because there is 100% internet connection and still it can’t connect to the firebase.
NOTE that the connection to firebase is happening AFTER the “Test of connection” is completed (my whole code is down below).

Also, as I said before: the script works when running from terminal/idle as intended. So I don’t even know how to troubleshoot and debug this code.

**What I think is happening is that the code can’t establish a connection to the firebase when running as service, but I don’t know why …**

**I have four main questions:**

1. Why the code can’t establish a connection to firebase when running
   as service using systemd? Even if there is 100% internet connection
   established.
2. Is there something that I need to add to the code so
   it can run as service?
3. I’m new to python (3 weeks of
   experience), so if there is something wrong that I’m doing, even tho
   it doesn’t affect the functionality, I’m open to any suggestions.
4. Is there a way to troubleshoot/debug this kind of stuff? Because I
   have no idea how to do so ...

**Here is the systemd service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/FirebaseTest/firebaseTest.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I was following these two tutorials:
[Tutorial 1](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/) and [Tutorial 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78991/running-a-script-after-an-internet-connection-is-established)

**And this is my code (I’m sorry that I'm adding the whole code but I didn't think of a way to how to split it into meaningful parts):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Libraries:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pyrebase
from time import sleep

try:
    import httplib
except:
    import http.client as httplib

#My functions:
def updateLED(status_LED, adr_LED): #Function that just update status of LED based on address and data 
    if status_LED == "ON":
        GPIO.output(adr_LED, GPIO.HIGH)

    if status_LED == "OFF":
        GPIO.output(adr_LED, GPIO.LOW)
        
    return

def have_internet(): #Function that returns true if there is internet connection, false if theres not
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com", timeout=5)
    try:
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        conn.close()
        return True
    except:
        conn.close()
        return False

#Cleanup of pins + turn off warnings + GPIO pins will be mapped as BCM
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)

#Set pins to OUTputs or INputs
LED1_adr = 18 #Adress of LED
GPIO.setup(LED1_adr, GPIO.OUT)

#Variables:
LED1 = "NULL"

#Test of connection ...
GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.HIGH)
while have_internet() == False:
    GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.LOW)
    print("No connection ...")
    sleep(1)

GPIO.output(LED1_adr, GPIO.HIGH)


#Main references to firebase and its config:
config = {
    "apiKey": "my apiKey",
    "authDomain": "my authDomain",
    "databaseURL": "my databseURL",
    "storageBucket": "my storageBucket",
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
database = firebase.database()


#Stream handler for reading realtime changes
def stream_handler(message):
    global LED1
    LED1 = message["data"]

my_stream = database.child("/led1/status").stream(stream_handler)
        
#Main functions:

while True:
    sleep(0.25)
    updateLED(LED1, LED1_adr)
```

Comment: I assume, running from `systemd` is to **early**, no python evironment ready. Try from `/etc/rc.local` and check to have a proper `PATH` set.

Comment: I've actually used `/etc/rc.local` before the `systemd`. And also when I was using `/etc/rc.local` I added **60 second delay** into the python code so that the Raspberry PI would have enough time to establish internet connection.

Strange think is that I have an **exact** same problem when running the script from `/etc/rc.local` or as a service using `systemd`.

Comment: + I know my path was okay (at least I think) in the `/etc/rc.local`, because I've tried to run different programs before the `firebaseTest.py` and they worked okay (just simple sketch to turn on and off LED).

Comment: For testing, use a slimed down script having only the `import ...` statements, add `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Run your test.py using `/usr/bin/python3 <path_to>test.py >> /tmp/test.py.log 2>&1`.

Comment: Will try! And do you want me to run the "slimed down script" using `terminal` or from `/etc/rc.local` or like a service using `systemd`?

Comment: The same point you want to use, i recommend `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: This is the output in the test.py.log: `['/home/pi/Desktop/FirebaseTest', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']` I have absolutly no idea what this means or what I have just achieved by doing this.

Comment: Looks good, no errors. Try with your failed script using also `>> /tmp/test.py.log 2>&1` at the end.

Comment: Should I add to my `firebaseTest.py` also the `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` ... ?
Because if no - the output in the logfile without the `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` is nothing. Just pure file.

Comment: Put some trace output in the code, e.g. in `have_internet():` before `return ...`, `print('have_internet() == True')` and in `def stream_handler():, print('stream_handler({}).format(message)')`

Comment: Okey I put the `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` to my code ... it still prints nothing into the output file. Here is what I have in my `/etc/rc.local` : `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/FirebaseTest/firebaseTest.py & >> /tmp/test.py.log 2>&1` Is it possible that I have something wrong there? For example - should I put the `/tmp/test.py.log 2>&1` before the `&` or after it? Will also try your suggestion to put output in the functions.

Comment: *"before the & or after it? "*: before, should be `Test.py >> /tmp/test.py.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: Okay I put some output into the code, specifically when connection is established it will print out “connection established”, and in the stream handler I just print the raw data from the message. **When I run it thorough terminal it prints everything without problem**. But when I start it on reboot nothing appears in the output file. This is what I have in my `/etc/rc.local` file after implementing what you suggested: `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/FirebaseTest/firebaseTest.py >> /tmp/test.py.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: Hi! Here is link for the [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/Sulomus/7ed942cd5b422a6cfdc24fc6e83f2b5d) I just created! Will be so thankful for any help!